# Can I disable the Bonjour Service?

Tags: windows-8.1, bonjour

I've got a Windows 8.1 machine. I don't own an iPhone. I do have some low-end iPod nanos, none of which have Bluetooth or anything else that I'm aware of which uses Wi-Fi. So, can I just disable the Bonjour Service?

Comment: Yes, you can uninstall it. Here is some info that might be useful ==> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control Panel, Programs and Features - Look for Bonjour Service and uninstall. When iTunes decides to update it will reappear though.